# Calculating sieve screen size

Tags: mathematics

I have a lot of mixed Lego, is it possible to calculate sieve screen dimensions to sort out particularly lego categories like bricks or plates ?

So you can say if I use this screen size and dimensions of holes i will sort out xx% of this range of items.

I think it should be possible but i do not know how to start.
I want to calculate it from a mathemical point of view.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: For some geometric shapes this is possible, for others it is not. One could, for instance, not separate a cylinder and a hollow cylinder of same outer dimensions with a sieve, alone. That would require an additional mechanism, e.g. separation by mass or average density.

Comment: This is similar to any stone&gravel quarry's  sifter, which uses a sequence of fine-to-coarse sieves to separate sand, gravel, small stones, large stones.   The longer you "shake" over a given sieve, the higher percentage of objects which **can** fall thru actually **do** fall thru.

Comment: but is it possible to calculate the optimal geometry to let throug tine objects (plates) or only thick objects (bricks) ?